# QAction Qt::Key_Return shortcut is triggered by user entering values in GUI

Tags: qt, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an issue with associating a keypress to a `QAction`. I'm mapping <kbd>Enter</kbd> to an action like this:

```
myAction->setShortcut(Qt::Key_Return);
```

The problem is that the `QAction` is also triggered when I type a value in a `QSpinBox` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I was expecting the spinbox to consume the event (so it's not caught by the mainwindow) but it's not working like that.

I've seen that I can add a context to my shortcut, I tried all values but this does not solve my issue.

@Matthew It is indeed rejecting the event:

```
case Qt::Key_Enter:
case Qt::Key_Return:
    d->edit->d_func()->control->clearUndo();
    d->interpret(d->keyboardTracking ? AlwaysEmit : EmitIfChanged);
    selectAll();
    event->ignore();
    emit editingFinished();
    return;
```

I find this behavior quite strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my knowledge the `QSpinBox` default behavior does wait until you press <kbd>return</kbd> to accept the value. Technically the value is set/accepted as soon as you change it.

If you're looking to change that behaviour, i.e. when you hit <kbd>return</kbd> on your `QSpinBox` you the value is actually set/accepted, then you will most likely have to handle the associated key press event yourself on the `QSpinBox` and mark it as accepted (i.e. `event->accepted()` ).

Otherwise, this sounds like it is working as originally designed although not as you want.

Comment: My problem is not with the QSPinBox accepting the value. The problem is that the enter event is not 'eaten' by the QSpinBox. So the same keystroke triggers the accept value from the QSpinBox (ok) but it triggers my QAction too! (not ok)

Comment: @JulienM Exactly, the default behaviour of the `QSpinBox` does not consume that event. So you will have to implement your own custom class derived from `QSpinBox` to consume the event.

Comment: But that would mean that I also need to subclass all the QWidget that I may add in the mainwindow and that do not consume the enter event!

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, only in PyQt and with QLineEdit

It may be that QActions are always considered menu actions, or global, and have a higher priority than Widget Default keys.

My "solution" was to create a global list of my actions with important keys (Return, Tab, Backspace etc.) as shortcuts.

Then I hook into QLineEdit focusInEvent and focusOutEvent. Each time the event happens I loop over the actions-list and deactivate them all on focusIn and activate them again on focusOut. Then I give the event to the original focus event handlers.

I really hope there is a better solution.